# Java 2-D random walk limited to four directions

Tags: java, random, boolean

I’m writing a typical 2-D random walk. However, the cursor can only move in cardinal directions. I wrote this method to test the code but it doesn’t exclude diagonal moves (when the x and y values are equal). That’s where I’m stuck. I could select a random integer between 1 and 4 and use nested ifs, but it seems there should be a simpler way using Boolean types since it's a binary decision. Am I on the right track?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

    //assume x & y are already initialized       

    Random xmove = new Random();
    Random ymove = new Random();

    // select new x-coord
    if (xmove.nextBoolean()) {
        x += 1;
    } else {
        x += -1;
    }

    // select new y-cord
    if (ymove.nextBoolean()) {
        y += 1;
    } else {
        y += -1;
    }

    System.out.printf("(%d, %d)", x, y);
    System.out.println();         
}
```

Comment: If you've got four possible moves, you need to generate one random number per move with four possible values.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, there are 4 possible moves (x+1, x-1, y+1, y-1), thus the decision it's not binary. However you don't need nested ifs either: just choose which action occurs on which outcome.

```
if (move == 0) {
    x += 1;
} else if (move == 1) {
    x += -1;
} else if (move == 2) {
    y += 1;
} else {
    y += -1;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that works perfectly. As you noted, I was incorrectly thinking of it as a binary choice and got my Boolean stuck in my head. Thanks.